# PATINDEX return wrong value?

Tags: return, patindex

Why does `PATINDEX('%n%','nguyen')` return value 6, not the first occurrence, but `PATINDEX('%n%','nathan')` return a value of 1, the first occurrence?

Comment: check your data, I get return value 1 for both

Comment: are you missing the trailing % in the first call?  That would cause it to return 6.  PATINDEX('%n', 'nguyen')

Comment: Sorry, I'm Vietnamese, my foreign language not very good!
I was try again with code: PATINDEX('%n%','nguyen'), but it's return 6. I do not create Database, I just execute code: Select PATINDEX('%n%','nguyen'), how to show my image in my comment? Thanks

Comment: I think you have a problem with your search term.

PATINDEX('%n%', 'nguyen') will return 1
PATINDEX('%n', 'nguyen') will return 6, notice that the second example is missing a %

Comment: @JSR: please view this image: http://postimg.org/image/xzyreone7/